# Problem connecting to Postgres docker image when not using RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have a really weird issue I'm experiencing. I have a Docker image for my postgres db, and another one for my rails app.

When I'm in `RAILS_ENV=development` (or `test`), I see the postgres image allowing connections at `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`, and I can also verify the postgres server is running. I then see my web container creating databases on the Postgres server no problem. **The app works great**.

When I'm in `RAILS_ENV=production`, I see the postgres image allowing connections at `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`, and I can STILL verify the postgres server is running. **But my web container now spits out an error that it cannot connect to the database at `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` (which is identical to the postgres image's path!).**

I've tried creating another environment that is identical to development in every way (`environments/development.rb` + `database.yml`), and it still doesn't work. I have no clue how this could possibly be.

I'm effectively cloning an environment that works, and ending with one that doesn't. Which makes me think there's something intrinsic with the development server that makes my docker setup work.

### databases.yml

```
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development
staging:
  <<: *default
  database: app_staging
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${APP_DATABASE_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data  

  webpacker:
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME-app}
    command: bash -c "export NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096" && yarn && rm -rf /opt/app/public/packs && bin/webpack-dev-server"
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app
    ports:
      - 3035:3035

  web:
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME-app}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        precompileassets: 'not'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - webpacker
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && /usr/wait-for-it.sh --timeout=0 db:5432  && rails db:create && rails db:migrate && rails s -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/app
```